# Runuser Not Return Expected Results

Tags: shell, ubuntu-18.04

There are two accounts in my linux computer, appuser and root. For testing purpose I wroto below code into /home/appuser/.profile

```
export key=value
```

then as root I execute below commands separately:

```
1. runuser -l appuser -c "echo key=$key"

   expected： key=value
   result:    key=   

2. runuser -l appuser -c "/home/appuser/test.sh"

    test.py includes only two lines:

    #!/bin/bash
    echo "key=$key"

    expected： key=value
    result:    key=value
```

Why can't the first command return the correct result?? Is that because .profile is not sourced during execution? why?

Comment: Yes, whatever shell you are using is not sourcing your `.profile` which contains the `key` declaration and assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> runuser -l appuser -c "echo key=$key"
> ```

Because it's in double quotes, `$key` is evaluated in the context of the current shell, not the shell you're launching. It's not set in your shell, so the command that is run is effectively:

```
runuser -l appuser -c 'echo key='
```

The variable never even makes it to the `runuser` command.

Use single quotes or escape the dollar sign to prevent interpolation.

```
runuser -l appuser -c 'echo key=$key'
runuser -l appuser -c "echo key=\$key"
```

Further reading:

- [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you did , didn't call "bash"..... and that users profile wasn't read.

When you ran the bash shell script, the first line initiates "bash"..... and from man "bash" :

"When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if
that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands  from  the  first  one
that exists and is readable."